# PHP split array by key

Tags: php

I have an array which looks like this:

```
array (
  'id' => 1,
  'channel_id' => 1,
  'field_group' => 1,
  'url_title' => 'the_very_first_entry',
  'title' => 'The Very First Entry',
  'fields' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'label' => 'Enter Item Name:',
      'type' => 'text',
      'channel_data_id' => 1,
      'value' => 'Item one',
      'field_id' => 1
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'label' => 'Enter Item Description',
      'type' => 'textarea',
      'channel_data_id' => 2,
      'value' => 'Some long text blah blah',
      'field_id' => 2
    )
   )
  )
```

I want to split this into 2 arrays, one containing the fields, and the other containing everything else, ie.

Array 1:

```
array (
  'id' => 1,
  'channel_id' => 1,
  'field_group' => 1,
  'url_title' => 'the_very_first_entry',
  'title' => 'The Very First Entry'
);
```

Array 2:

```
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'label' => 'Enter Item Name:',
      'type' => 'text',
      'channel_data_id' => 1,
      'value' => 'Item one',
      'field_id' => 1
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'label' => 'Enter Item Description',
      'type' => 'textarea',
      'channel_data_id' => 2,
      'value' => 'Some long text blah blah',
      'field_id' => 2
    )
   )
```

Is there a better solution that iterating through the original array with a foreach loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a better solution that iterating through the original array with a foreach loop

You know the split-key so there's no real use for `foreach`:

```
$src = array(...);   // your source array
$fields_array = $src['fields'];
unset($src['fields']);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I've got at the moment. I thought there might be a "better" solution in the form of a native php function that outputted the 2 desired parts of the original array without the need to unset.

Comment: There's are some other methods you could use but all other answers that seem to try to do that are fundamentally broken, either by assuming fields is last element of an array, requiring more steps to achieve the goal or not working properly with some cases. Keep simple things simple :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct.

```
<?php

$base = array(...); // your array

// array values
$baseArrays = array_filter($base, function($item){
  return is_array($item);
});

// not array values
$not = array_diff($base, $baseArrays);
```

Comment: This one is broken too :) Add non array to the $base array (i.e. object) and you get $baseArray polluted by it which is not what OP wanted.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski if you change the name of `fields` to `options` your answer is also broken. I just show idea how to filter out something from the array and split it by two. What to put into callable is up to OP.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, *if* the `fields` key is always the last element of the array, you can use `array_pop`.

```
$fields = array_pop($array);
```

And that's it. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/QPZ5J).